# vscode display documentation in new tab/window

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs, popup, window, documentation

I have been using kite(python) for the past few months and I really like how I can just glance at my other monitor to view all the documentation of a function. The main thing that I like about it is that it updates pretty much instantly when my cursor moves to another function(-call) and that I can span it over a large area on my display so I see all the documentation at once.

I was wondering if this or something similar can be done within visual studio code itself. It can show a preview/the entire documentation of a function in a small popup so it must be possible to show it in a separate tab that also updates when your cursor moves to another function, right?

TL;DR: I want to view the documentation of the function under my cursor in a separate window.

Is this possible? How can I configure this?

Comment: `I want to view the documentation of the function under my cursor in a separate window.` if a [peek](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_peek)  definition is not considered a separate window to you, then not that I am aware of, especially one that auto updates as you move about.  You can always use `CRTL+SHIFT+SPACE` to popluate method info (Not the same I know). Of course, I could be wrong that's why I'm posting a comment, but I don't think there is functionality to open in a new window, and I'm certain there isn't functionality that updates depending on cursor placement

Comment: Additionally, `CTRL+SPACE` specifically opens what vscode calls 'suggestion details' which usually includes documentation of sorts, or [custom data](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/custom-data-sample)